# ssmtp with sparkpost in docker

Tags: docker, smtp, sparkpost, ssmtp

I'm trying to set up a simple email server for testing during development, but SSMTP keeps giving me "Invalid response SMTP server" even with `-vvvv`, I get no more information.

My ssmtp config file looks like this right now:

```
root=my-email@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.sparkpostmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=email.codyhaines.com
fromLineOverride=yes
useSTARTTLS=yes
useTLS=yes
AuthMethod=AUTH LOGIN
AuthUser=SMTP_Injection
AuthPass=MY_SPARK_POST_API_KEY
```

I've set up the domain through sparkpost, and verified it with the TXT DNS record, my API_KEY has 'Send via SMTP' enabled. Not sure what's wrong with the config and why it's not sending.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the network I was on. It seems the "Invalid response SMTP server" error is almost always a result of either connecting to a bad address or firewall issues (either on your local device, or your network). In my case, I was using a local coffee shop's wifi, and they blocked all non-standard ports, so it wasn't connecting.